# Gevent ready memcache client?

Tags: memcached, gevent

I see that there's a port of memcache client for gevent (https://github.com/hjlarsson/gevent-memcache), but it has not been updated since August 2010.  Do you guys have any recommendation on a memcache client for using in gevent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one, released and maintained by the guys at www.esn.me

https://github.com/esnme/ultramemcache

They also have a faster JSON decoder as well, coded in C with python binding.

Answer (score 2):

There is the python-ultramemcache that give the same interface as python-memcache, but use ultramemcache. So you only need to change your import if you already use python-memcache:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ultramemcached/0.0.2

To install:

```
pip install python-ultramemcache
```

Then in your code:

```
import ultramemcache as memcache
```